# Как сохранить изображение по URL в БД в формате Base 64?

Tags: java, android

Работаю с `Room` , задача такая: получаю с сервера `url` картинки и нужно его сохранить в БД

Как лучше это сделать? сохранить как файл на устройстве и ссылку на него сохранить в БД?

Или скачать как `Bitmap` конвертировать в `Base64` и сохранить в БД (вот тут не совсем представляю как это сделать)?

**EDIT**

Мне нужно понять как выполнить процесс сохранения. Вот такой вам вопрос , вам дали url и сказали сохранить в BD в формате Base64 , ваши действия? Как будете скачивать как вытягивать Bitmap ? И будет ли вообще это верное решение, если нет то почему?

**EDIT** 
Вопрос НЕ В ТОМ КАК СОХРАНИТЬ КАКРТИНКУ В БД, а в том как ее сохранить в формате 'Base64' и нормально ли ИМЕННО В ЭТОМ ФОРМАТЕ ее сохранять

Comment: "нужно его сохранить в BD", картинку или url? Больше конкретики

Comment: Что значит изображение с url?

Comment: @iamtihonov вопрос достаточно простой(если внимательно прочитать) , согласно вопросу : есть два возможных пути сохранить картинку в бд 1)сначала сохранить ее локально и в бд сохранить ссылку 2) сохранить картинку в формате `Base64` - вот именно это меня интересует

Comment: @iamtihonov значит, что есть `url` на картинку и нужно ее сохранить

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko не думаю, что хранить картинки в БД - хороший вариант, выбирайте 1 путь - локально в файл а ссылку в БД. Хотя вообще зачем это нужно? Вы все равно забираете с сервера картинку чем то вроде Picasso или Glade, а там есть свой КЭШ картинок локальный, он гибко настраивается...

Comment: @mit я понимаю, что у пикасо есть кэш, но есть ситуации когда пользователь выходит с приложения и когда открывает его снова, то при условии , что нет интернета нужно показать ему последний результат. Вот тут то я и должен показать ему это изображение. А почему вы считаете, что `Base64` формат не подойдет для этой задачи, ведь сохраняется как `String`

Comment: Вы можете только хранить путь для изображения, но не сам файл в базе, никому такого не говорите больше

Comment: кто то изменил заголовок моего вопроса. Вопрос был в том как сохранить в формате Base64

Comment: тогда да, если вы используете MySQL, то посмотрите поле LONGTEXT
там помоему 60к+ символов можно

Answer (score 1):

Скачать и вытащить битмап можно, к примеру с помощью Glade, примерно так:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(path)
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
            // здесь конвертируете и сохраняете битмап
        }
    });
```

Если вам нужна все же функция конвертирования, то используйте пакет `android.util.Base64` примерно так:

```
public static String bitmapToEncodedString(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

Но в целом, хранить картинки в БД - не стоит. Все конечно зависит от ситуации (количество, объем). Все эти операции с огромными строками в БД и конвертацией на клиенте - лишние накладные расходы. Мы и на бэкэнде не храним никакие картинки в БД, ни в стрингах, ни в блобах, ни в клобах... Почему - отдельнаый вопрос для дискуссии.

Comment: Та не нужна мне функция конвертирования) Мне нужно понять как выполнить процесс сохранения. Вот такой вам вопрос , вам дали `url` и сказали сохранить в `BD` в формате `Base64` , ваши действия? Как будете скачивать как вытягивать `Bitmap` ? И будет ли вообще это верное решение, если нет то почему?

Comment: о, вот это похоже на правду) не встречал раньше такой подход.

Answer (score 1):

В сохранении картинки в БД нет ничего суперсложного, надо просто озаботиться 3 вещами:

1) Сохранять массив `byte[]` в поле типа BLOB

2) Писать кусками (*chunk*) - ну скажем по 1 мб. (не помню по-моему по документации SQLite длина поля не может быть более 2 мб или 20 мб - посмотрите сами уж)

3) Раз пишем кусочками, то надо озаботиться номером кусочка

Без понятия как это делать на Room (не изучал его еще), но на старом добром SQLite напрямую это делалось так (случай чтения файла/картинки из ресурсов):

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().open(R.drawable.MyImageFile);
try {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
    int size = CHUNK_SIZE;
    int order=0;
    while(size == CHUNK_SIZE) {
        size = is.read(buffer);  //чтение кусков 
        if (size == -1) 
            break;
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(CHUNK, buffer);       //CHUNK имя поля с типом BLOB
        cv.put(ORDER, order++);        //ORDER имя поля куда пишем номер куска

        long rowId = database.insert(MYTABLE, null, cv); 
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error saving raw image to: "+rawId, e);
}
```

Уверен, вы легко адаптируете код к случаю, когда надо читать картинку по заданному URL и заодно к Room также.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сначала архитектурно решить, что вы будете хранить в бд. Оффлайн хранение данных на аппарате - хорошо, но требует места. Судя по постановке вопроса, есть потребность в картинках оффлайн. И тут я вижу 2 подхода:

1. Хранить превьюхи, либо сжатые до формата экрана каотинки. Это
   сэкономит место, если не требуется их зумить.
2. Хранить полностью картинки. Тут просто нужно много памяти.  Так или иначе, для хранения картинок в base64,  вам нужно сделать

Конвертация переменной `bitmap` класса `Bitmap` в ответе [выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/867763/299602)

Comment: Чем этот ответ отличается от того который над вашим?