# Как выгрузить файл (не только картинку) на сервер в base64 android retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, base64

У меня уже есть вопрос по этой теме - [Как конвертировать файлы в base64 android?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/904320/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-base64-android) в котором мне подсказали что нужно использовать библиотеку okhttp3 и multipart вместо того способа который я предложил как решение своего вопроса. Погуглив про библиотеку и метод передачи файла я понял что чисто гипотетически это может решить мою проблему но так и не понял каким именно образом.

Какая стоит задача - выгружать фалы на сервер как в любом более-менее нормальном почтовом клиенте. Имеется в виду выгружать не только картинку, а любой файл. Обязательное условие - файлы должны быть в формате base64.

Что я понял и узнал - чтобы файл конвертировать в base64 нам сначала нужно его перегнать в string и потом уже в base64. Но тот способ который я привел в своем вопросе не подходит потому что он будет перегружать ОЗУ а мне этого не нужно. Вроде как можно выгружать файлы на сервер при помощи multipart но я так и не понял в каком формате будет в итоге файл на сервере. Выгрузка файлов будет проходить не отдельным запросом, а будет идти вместе с отправкой самого письма, то есть в тело запроса будет вставлен еще и массив с файлом (файлами). Вот что нужно докинуть в запрос отправки сообщения:

```
"attach": [
{"filename": "preved.doc",  "data": BASE64_FILE_ENCODED},
...
]
```

Я не могу понять как это все будет происходить и как это правильно делать. Если кто-то занимался подобным вопросом и у него есть решение, то я буду очень благодарен если вы поделитесь рабочим способом. Если же решения как такового нету, то буду благодарен даже за советы и рекомендации по тому как решить мою задачу.

Comment: Если у Вас **обязательное** условие `base64`, то `multypart` ему не замена. Вы лучше уточните способ передачи вложений, ибо кодировать в `base64` мега-, гига-байтные файлы - это извращение, поэтому Вам и посоветовали `multypart`-запрос. `base64` больше подходит для встраивания в текст мелких файлов (типа иконок 64х64, коротких звуков-пуков и т.п.) дабы не делать кучу дополнительных запросов по десятку байт каждый.

Comment: а что означает способ передачи файлов?

Comment: Можно ли использовать `multypart` или обязательно пихать файл в тело сообщения в виде `BASE64_FILE_ENCODED`. Пример мультипарт-запроса если что: [android-school.ru/retrofit-2-загружаем-файлы-на-сервер](https://android-school.ru/retrofit-2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80/).

Comment: @woesss, обязательно в base64, я просто не понял сразу что вы имеете в виду. на сервер будет слаться массив в формате json и его макс размер будет равен 20мб.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/867731/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-url-%D0%B2-%D0%91%D0%94-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5-base-64/867763#867763] (посмотрите здесь) там в ответе приводится метод для конвертирования файла в base64

Comment: @mit, в приведенном вами вопросе все расписано красиво и хорошо, но насколько я понял там было рассмотрено только конвертирование картинки в base64 а я хочу любой файл конвертировать, либо я не там смотрел